# How to capture/log all errors from Amazon AWS JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I want to hook a function to log all errors from the AWS JavaScript SDK, ideally at one single point for everything.

I've dug around for several hours but not found the right point.

Can anyone suggest where/how this can be done?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what your doing actually in the AWS, but it should look something like this. You didn't give us really anything to work with.

```
    // Depends on parameters
    AWS(function(error, response) {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error)
     } else if (response) {
    console.log("No errors + a response")
    }
  }
```